# Are MediaWiki API redirects broken?

Tags: redirect, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

I can't figure out how to get them to work.  According to the official API documentation:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Resolving_redirects

it would imply that the following request:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Hybrid%20Cars&prop=info|links&redirects

would resolve Hybrid Cars and redirect to Hybrid Vehicles page, but it does not.  I.e., I expected something like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Hybrid%20Vehicles&prop=info|links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The page `Hybrid Cars`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Cars) does not exist, so the result you're getting (with the `missing` attribute) is correct. You probably meant [`Hybrid cars`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hybrid_cars&redirect=no), which is a redirect to `Hybrid vehicle`. Page names on Wikipedia are case sensitive except for the first letter.

If you use the correct capitalization, you will get the correct results:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Hybrid%20cars&prop=info|links&redirects